# Remove flash object from session Grails

Tags: grails, grails-2.4

I want to remove the flash object from the session in Grails Application. I am doing with

`session.removeAttribute('org.codehaus.groovy.grails.FLASH_SCOPE')`

in the filter but it is throwing the following error:

```
com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.HazelcastSerializationException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.GrailsFlashScope
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.HazelcastSerializationException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.GrailsFlashScope
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:188) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
```

Is there any way better solution for removing the flash object from session?

Comment: Why do you want to remove the flash object?

Comment: Because i am using Hazelcast to store session objects and the grails flashscope object is throwing error. I havenot used it so want to remove it. Thanks

Comment: Have you contacted Hazelcast about this?  It may be a bug or they may be able to provide documentation on how to do this. It would definitely be in their interests to allow grails apps to be able to use the software.

Comment: Its not the issue of hazelcast because if i include the grails-web-common jar in backend(which is unnecessary), then the error stops. So I want to remove from the front(grails) project instead. Thanks

Comment: Yes, however they may have run into this - and it would be in their interests to solve this as well.  They could then add it into their documentation.

Comment: I don't know what is causing that error but be careful about removing flash if you are using plugins that might be referencing it.